# Get values from one class to another class

Tags: android, android-intent

I am passing values using Intent, but I am not able to receive in other class.

```
public class page4 extends Activity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.page4);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String list1 = intent.getStringExtra("list1");


        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        ImageAdapter adapter = new ImageAdapter(this);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);






    }


}
```

and I want to receive that intent in the following class.

```
public class ImageAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
}
```

Comment: do `new ImageAdapter(this,yourValue);`

Comment: create a constructor with a String parameter like `public ImageAdapter(Context ctx, String list1)`

Comment: intents are for passing data between 2 activities or services. for your pager adapter you just can pass the data in your constructor, setter method or what ever you want

Comment: wat abt extends PageAdapter

Comment: try with SharedPreferences .i don't know it helpful or not

Comment: Please provide the code where you are setting the data to the intent

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this directly. The easiest way to do it is to pass the needed extra `list1` in the `constructor` of your `ImageAdapter`:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    public ImageAdapter(Context context, String list1Details) {
        // Use your extra here
    }
}
```

Comment: wat abt extends pageAdapter

Comment: I gave you the Constructor of your class. The class itself extends the PagerAdapter

Comment: @namratha did you use this logic?

Answer (score 1):

Intent is used only when data is to be passed from Activity/Service to other. So in this case Intent is not required. Edit the following in your code

```
public class Page4 extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.page4);
    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    ImageAdapter adapter = new ImageAdapter(this,"String you want to pass");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

And add a constructor in the ImageAdapter class in the way I have mentioned below

```
public class ImageAdapter extends PagerAdapter{

    private Context context;
    private String passedString;

    public ImageAdapter(Context context, String passedString) {
    this.context = context;
    this.passedString = passedString;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
    return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return false;
    }
}
```